# Redirect from .php URL for only one specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just removed the .php extensions from my site and I want to redirect the old URLs to the new ones. In particular it's just for the picture.php file and none others. Pages are identical for both domain.com/picture/$1 and domain.com/picture.php/$1 and both resolve just fine, but I need to redirect all traffic from the .php extension to the non-php version.

I tried using this code which seems to work as far as showing the new correct non-.php URL in my address bar, but it breaks the site and shows a 404 for all the /picture pages.

RedirectMatch 301 ^/picture.php/(.*)$ http://domain.com/picture/$1

Do I perhaps have an error in the redirect rule? I've done some reading but I'm still new to writing rules. Is there any better method of doing this?

Thanks in advanced!

-Justin

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
<?php
      header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
?>
```

Be sure that you do not have any text sent to the browser before this, or it will not work. Your safest bet is to simply remove all content from the page but the redirect code.